# How does Python Re deal with a substring (multiple words) passed as a pattern?

Tags: python, string-matching, python-re

I am building a naive String-Matching algorithm with a source to search through. The algorithm uses re.finditer, and it works fine when supplying a single string like "crow" as a pattern, however, I get weird results that do not match the pattern when I try to search for a phrase, like "you know nothing, jon snow", it either does not find it, or finds something else, completely unrelated. That leads me to believe that there is a problem with passing a straight string as a pattern, probably related to whitespaces.

Code:

```
def naiveMatch(pattern, text):
    print(pattern)
    i=0
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        print(match.start())
        i=i+1
    print("I: ", i)
```

As a basis for this test, I am using GOT dialogue. The word "crow" matches 18 times in S3E2. The string "You know nothing, Jon Snow" matches in Episode 2 as well, even though it shouldn't be there. The position it matches is:
'r? This child? TYRION:  I '
In Episode 7, the string should be matched, but isn't.

This leads me to believe there is some issue with supplying this string without processing and giving it to the regex.

Comment: You've got some other bug. `re` doesn't do anything special or weird with that example string.

Comment: I looked at it again, and found that the program indeed matches correctly, but gives wrong filenames, i.e. what he says isnt in file 3, but actually in file 2.

Answer (score 0):

Update, this problem was actually caused by a wrong order of files in the os.listdir(), which put file 10 between file 1 and 2.

['e1.txt', 'e10.txt', 'e2.txt', 'e3.txt', 'e4.txt', 'e5.txt', 'e6.txt', 'e7.txt', 'e8.txt', 'e9.txt']

Problem was fixed by using a sorted() function with lambda to sort based on the numbers in the filenames.

`key=lambda a: int(re.search("[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?", a, flags=0).group(0)))`